# Python Unable to save file with slash in front of name

Tags: python, file, ipython

```
with open('/tests/testDict.pickle','wb') as fp: print 'to terminal'
```

What is wrong with the above it's driving me nuts an giving me the following:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IOError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-fe5a4a9f361c> in <module>()
----> 1 with open('/tests/testDict.pickle','wb') as fp: print 'to terminal'

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tests/testDict.pickle'
```

If I don't have a slash in front I get:

```
with open('tests/testDict.pickle','wb') as fp: print 'to terminal'
to terminal
```

I have the following directory structure in OS X:

```
$ ls
cp1.py           cp1_pdftest.jpg  random/          tests/
```

Comment: Does your root directory `/` include a directory `/tests` that the current user has permission to write?

Comment: In which directory did you run the `ls` command? `'/tests/testDict.pickle'` looks like an absolute path.

Comment: I think *Python script* and *tests folder* are at same level. is it so?

Comment: Possible you mean `./tests/testDict.pickle'`

Comment: `pwd` is the directory that `cp1.py` is contained in and this is the file that is running the code. I am generating the file location by : `test_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "/tests/")`

Comment: @AlexanderMcFarlane if you `print(test_dir)` you'll see that it's `./tests`, most likely.

Comment: @WayneWerner 
`In [29]: print test_dir` gives
`/tests/`

Comment: @AlexanderMcFarlane and `print os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())`?

Comment: That leading slash on "/tests/" forces the path to be absolute, even though you're doing `os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "/tests/")`. Try it with  `os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "tests/")`

Comment: @PM2Ring you are my hero of the day. that's it.

Comment: :) From [os.path.join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) "[...] If a component is an absolute path, all previous components are thrown away and joining continues from the absolute path component."

Comment: @PM2Ring by jove, you're right! I never would have guessed that. But then again I never bother with slashes in my arguments to `join`, I just assumed that it ensured there were only one slash between. Guess not!

Comment: This bit me once a couple of years ago, and I've _never_ forgotten. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That leading slash on `"/tests/"` forces the path to be absolute, even though you're doing

```
os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "/tests/")
```

So you need to do

```
os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "tests/")
```

From the [os.path.join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) docs:

> `os.path.join(path, *paths)`
>
> Join one or more path components intelligently. The return value is
>   the concatenation of `path` and any members of `*paths` with exactly one
>   directory separator (`os.sep`) following each non-empty part except
>   the last, meaning that the result will only end in a separator if the
>   last part is empty. **If a component is an absolute path, all previous
>   components are thrown away and joining continues from the absolute
>   path component.**

Comment: Brilliant explanation. It makes total sense to do this

Answer (score 3):

When you have the leading slash, it indicates an absolute path. That is, unless you have a directory called 'tests' in the root (`/`) directory of your system, this shouldn't work.

Comment: see edit. Apologies if I edited after you added this. I realised that it needed more information....

Comment: My answer stands. tests and /tests refer to different directories.

Comment: Thanks, I did schoolboy myself there. However, why is this code generating the root...? That's what caught me off guard

Answer (score 0):

`/` only is the root directory, maybe you should try with `./`